Why is the USRP X310 spectrum noisy without an external bandpass filter?
I am using an Ettus X310 USRP with UBX160 daugtherboards to collect 100 MHz of instantaneous bandwidth at 3.1 GHz. When I run this setup without an external bandpass filter, the spectrum appears noisy and full of interference, with fluctuations in the noise floor. Known signals are weak and difficult to detect.
However, after adding a bandpass filter between the antenna and the LNA, the spectrum becomes much cleaner, and the signal quality improves significantly.

What could be causing the interference and noise in the spectrum when the filter is not present?
Why isn’t the X310’s built-in filtering enough to prevent this interference?
Does the amount of bandwidth being captured impact the interference level?

Here is the receiver setup:
Antenna -> bandpass filter > low noise amplifier (LNA) -> software-defined radio

The noise is likely caused by strong out-of-band signals overloading either the preamp or the SDR. I'm betting that the overloading is taking place in the SDR, rather than the preamp.
If that's the case, then using a resistive attenuator between the preamp and the SDR will solve the problem without having to use the filter.
I suggest a pi attenuator made with small non inductive resistors. I don't know of a commercial source.

What is the preamp in this context? Is this the amplifier in the UBX160 daughterboard on the X310?

@BigBrownBear00 I thought that you added an external preamp. It's what you described as a low noise amplifier. No?

Yes, LNA before the SDR. This occurs with or without the LNA.

so you are saying attenuate the RF before it gets to the LNA/SDR and this will help?
